# Orthographic mode render

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

I'm trying to render in orthographic view, clicking on the cam, and going to settings choosing type: Orthographic. But when my PNG sequence is exported its still in perspective. What further more settings do I need to do?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your scene? Why did you add a modeling tag? Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Double-check if there is a different camera that your scene is using.

Comment: Did you set the camera to **Lens Type: Orthographic**? Do you have more than one camera? Is the camera the active camera for the layer/scene? It's hard to help you if you don't show the settings you are using.

Comment: Here's a screen shot.

I'm just practising how to export a PNG sequence. the cube goes from left to right. There is only one camera in the scene. And its set to orthographic.

https://ibb.co/DMkgbYn